# What does $\lg x$ mean? is it $\log_2 x$ or $\log_{10} x$ in binary trees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, definition, trees

I'm a bit confused, $\log_{10} x = \log x $ right? I believe I've read somewhere that $\log_{2} x = \lg x$ but some people say $\lg = \log$.

So what does $\lg$ really stand for? specifically when talking about "binary trees"

Comment: There are many different notations. In the context of binary trees, you'd probably talk about $\log_2$, but I've seen it marked as $\log$, $\log_2$ or $\lg$.

Comment: Almost certainly $\log_2$ $-$ the hint is in the word '*binary*'!

Answer (score 12):

$\lg$ will usually stand for $\log_2$ when talking about binary. In Germany and Russia, $\lg$ refers to $\log_{10}$. [Source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lg.html)

Comment: In Hungary as well

Answer (score 2):

It is common that $\lg=\log_2$, but note that $\log_a = \Theta(\log_b)$, because $$\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}.$$

Comment: This remark is interesting because for the most part algorithms evaluation do not care about multiplicative factors.

Answer (score 2):

The [ISO 80000 specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000), published in 2019, tries to resolve the numerous ambiguities in the notations for logarithms. It recommends the following notations:

$\lg x\equiv\log_{10}x\\
\ln x\equiv\log_e x\\
{\rm lb}\, x\equiv\log_2 x$.

These ISO recommendations try to avoid the ambiguity in the notations for the common logarithm ${\rm Log}\,  x\equiv\log x\equiv\log_{10} x$, as the same notation is sometimes used for the natural logarithm $\log x\equiv\ln x\equiv\log_e x$. The ISO rules also **discourage** the use of ${\rm lg}\, x\equiv\log_2 x$. See a discussion of the ambiguities [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases).